# TypeError: Argument 2 must support iteration (even though it does?)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python and am getting an error with the map function that doesn't make sense to me. When I call the function with a list as the second parameter it returns the error 'TypeError: Argument 2 must support iteration' which confuses me because a list should support iteration.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array(map(int, raw_input().split().reverse()), float))
```

The code is meant to take in a list, and print out a numpy that is the reverse of the list. Any help as to why the second paramter isn't iteratable would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you test just this: `raw_input().split().reverse()`?  Or even `'1 2 3'.split().reverse()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.reverse()` function reverses the list in-place and returns `None`. If you want to write this as one line you may write `reversed(raw_input().split())` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`.reverse()` does the reverse in-place and returns `None`.

Get rid of the `.reverse()` and call `reversed()` instead like so, which should fix your issue:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array(map(int, reversed(raw_input().split())), float))
```